# How to take exact number of inputs to a list from user using list.split()

Tags: python, list, sorting

Input Description:
First line contains the number of arrays. Subsequent lines contain the size of the array followed by the elements of the array.

Output Description:
An array containing the sorted elements of k sorted arrays

```
Sample Input :
3
2
98 12
6
1 2 3 8 5 9
1
11
Sample Output :
12 98 1 2 3 5 8 9 11
```

code I tried:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
  k=int(input())
  for i in range(k):
    l.append(input().split())
 print(*sorted(l))
```

for the first input of 2 numbers ,i need to give 2 numbers to input (98,12) by using input().split() but since the inner loop is excuting twice ,i'm ending up with giving input twice

Comment: What problem do you have here? Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: for the first input of 2 numbers ,i need to give 2 numbers to input (98,12) by using input().split() but since the inner loop is excuting twice ,i'm ending up with giving input twice

Comment: Are the 98 and the 12 entered et the same time or one after the other? If they are, why do you need the loop? Otherwise, just do `l.append(input())`

Comment: How to make sure that exactly 2 numbers are entered using l.append(input())

Comment: Your second `for` loop get executed only `k` times, where `k` is the number you entered before typing all the values of your list.

Comment: Using l.append(input()) how to make sure that exactly k numbers are entered?

Comment: I have detailed my thoughts in an answer, see below and let me know if anything's not clear

Answer (score 0):

You were on a good lead with what you tried, but you mixed a few things when you try to enter the values to fill your lists.
Let's use the following skeleton:

```py
number_of_lists = int(input('Enter the number of lists : '))
for list_number in range(1, number_of_lists+1):
    current_list = []
    number_of_values = int(input('Enter the number of values in the list #%d : ' % list_number))
    # Here we enter the values of the current list,
    # and that's where things will differ a bit
    print('The list is : %s' % str(current_list))
    print('The sorted list is: %s' % str(sorted(current_list)))
```

Depending on how the values of your list are entered, things will differ a bit:

- If they are entered one by one (ie. you type one, then press Enter, then an other,...)
- If they are entered all in the same line, separated by spaces, you won't need a `for` loop, instead you will have to split the input on the spaces to fill your list.

**Case 1 :** you enter the values one by one

In this case, the number of values you can put in your list is controlled by the number you entered before which is used in the `for` loop.

```py
number_of_lists = int(input('Enter the number of lists : '))
for list_number in range(1, number_of_lists+1):
    current_list = []
    number_of_values = int(input('Enter the number of values in the list #%d : ' % list_number))
    for value_number in range(number_of_values):
        value = int(input("Enter the value : "))
        current_list.append(value)
    print('The list is : %s' % str(current_list))
    print('The sorted list is: %s' % str(sorted(current_list)))
```

**Case 2 :** you enter all the values in the same line, all them separated by

In case, there's no need of a `for` loop because you get all the values at the same time, but this requires you to check that you've got the right amount of values.

Multiple strategies for this :

1. You trust the user to enter the right amount of values (I don't suggest this)
2. You ask the user for inputs until he has entered enough values
3. You add values if there's not enough and remove some if there's too much

*First possibility*: You simply asks the user to enter the values:

```py
all_values = input("Enter all the values : ").split()
```

*Second possibility*: You have to use a `while` loop in which you ask the user for the values until you have enough:

```py
all_values = []
while len(all_values) != number_of_values:
    all_values = input("Enter all the values : ").split()
    if len(all_values) != number_of_values:
        # Warning message for the user, not required but a good thing
        print("You didn't enter enough values, try again.")
```

*Third possibility*: You add values hen the user hasn't entered enough, and remove some when he has given you more:

```py
all_values = input("Enter all the values : ").split()
if len(all_values) < number_of_values:
    # We don't have enough values... What do we do ?
    # Let's add 0's at the end, this will not change the final order
    while len(all_values) < number_of_values:
        all_values.append(0)
elif len(all_values) > number_of_values:
    # We have too much values... What do we do ?
    # Let's try to remove the last value until we have enough values
    while len(all_values) > number_of_values:
        all_values.pop()
```

Once you have the right amount of values, you still need to make every item a integer:

```py
current_list = [int(item) for item in all_values]
```

You can finally sort your list and print it, and *voilà*!.

To sum up this case, use the skeleton I provide in the top, and use one of the three possibilities to enter the values of the lists.

**Conclusion**
So which one to use? Well, you may have guessed I suggest you to use the first case, it's simplier to use and to understand.

Though if you want to use the second case, you still need to choose how you'd control the amount of values you get:

- I strongly discourage you to choose the first possibility, it's never a good choice in computer science to trust the user with the data he provides you (well not you directly, but your program,...).
- The second is interesting as it forces the user to enter the exact amount of values, no less, no more.
- The third one is less restrictive on this point because it can deal with more or less values than what's expected, but this may also be it's bad point.

Hope this help!